# Trying understand function and why it gives this result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Someone wrote(he left company) following function:

```
Create function code_status
( p_code_id varchar, 
  p_daytime date, 
  p_status varchar);

  Select status into l_value from table1 where code_id=p_code_id and daytime=p_daytime;

  Return l_value;
  End;
```

And use it in sql query below:

```
Select code, daytime, status, code_status(code_id, daytime, status) from  table2 
where code_status(code_id, daytime, status) in ('act') and daytime = '12 Jan 2017'
```

When I run select query from function to get all rows for code = 'f23'

```
Select code, code_id, daytime, status from table1 where code = 'f23';
```

It gives following result:

```
Code   code_id  status   daytime
F23    123df     act     16 Jul 2016
F23    123df     stn     12 Jan 2017
F23    123df     act     15 Mar 2017
```

When I run query below it gives following result:

```
Select code, daytime, code_id,status, code_status(code_id, daytime, status)  stat_funct 
from table2 
where code_status(code_id, daytime, status) in ('act') 
  and daytime = '12 Jan 2017' 
  and code='f23'
```

```
Code   daytime      code_id   status    stat_funct 
F23    12 Jan 2017   123df     act      act
```

Now I'm trying to understand what this function does and how it works in query, why stat_funct is 'act'?

Comment: there is no multiple the same code_id for different code, code assigned to only single code_id.

Comment: Can it because of " and daytime = '12 Jan 2017' " ?

Comment: It's probably mostly being inefficient, at least how you're calling it - you're essentially joining table1 to table2 in your query, but indirectly via the function. The `p_status` value isn't used. You may have data duplicated in both tables, but it's hard to tell from the sample from one of them. The `stat_funct` is just the status value from `table1`. What is in `table2`?

Comment: That function was written for what is known as "job security" :) Sorry, couldn't help it.

Answer (score 0):

It's abstracting the access to the `status` field of `table2` using the supplied parameters and naming it "code_status". The fact that table1 and table2 have similar schemas is coincidental, but it does mean the function could be replaced with a join (which would perform far better).

The reasons for creating this was presumably to make it easier to use in a simple query (to avoid a join), or for security reasons (where all access to data is via SPs, and security is handled by granting access to SPs instead of tables - IMHO an anti-pattern).